# Apache Airflow - mysql 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes'

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

Trying to set up Airflow for MySQL and I am getting an error while Airflow attempts to set the primary key during "airflow initdb"

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1071, 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes') [SQL: u'\nCREATE TABLE sla_miss (\n\ttask_id VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, \n\tdag_id VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, \n\texecution_date DATETIME NOT NULL, \n\temail_sent BOOL, \n\ttimestamp DATETIME, \n\tdescription TEXT, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (task_id, dag_id, execution_date), \n\tCHECK (email_sent IN (0, 1))\n)\n\n']
```

Messed around with this for a while and could not exactly get it to work out.

I know that the key is too long for the database but I am hoping that there is another way I can try to create the database to get this to work?

From this example http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-and-configuring-apache-airflow/ I tried this:

```
CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But that still caused the errors. When i change the CHARACTER SET to latin1 it is able to create the database but then none of the actual airflow processes are able to run due to decode errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think I was able to get this to work. I changed my original create database to CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET ascii and updated my engine to have /airflow?charset=ascii. Seems like it is working now (which is amazing)